# Win7 x64 large copy File creation error - The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: windows-7, usb-storage, file-transfer

I have spent all day trying to copy a 680GB file from an NTFS USB3.0 drive (Disk #2 below) to an NTFS USB2.0 drive (Disk #3 below) with plenty of free, unfragmented space.

I have tried it in both Windows Explorer and from command prompt using `xcopy /J`.  The latter, after about an hour, reports,

```
    File creation error - The semaphore timeout period has expired.
```

I have tried the following to fix this:

1. Turned off all power-saving features
2. Updated my USB drivers
3. Tried [this](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/mapped-drive-gets-disconnected-while-copying-large-files-in-vista/)

Here is my MSINFO32.  Let me know of anything else I might check to debug or workaround:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Other OS Description Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model To be filled by O.E.M.
System Type x64-based PC
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3225 CPU @ 3.30GHz, 3300 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical    Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. F9, 8/22/2012
SMBIOS Version 2.7
Windows Directory C:\Windows
System Directory C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "6.1.7601.17514"
Time Zone Eastern Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory 15.5 GB
Available Physical Memory 7.99 GB
Total Virtual Memory 30.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory 21.8 GB
Page File Space 15.5 GB
Page File C:\pagefile.sys
```

Drive #2:
    Manufacturer (Standard disk drives)
    Model Fantom External HDD USB Device
    Bytes/Sector 4096
    Media Loaded Yes
    Media Type Removable media
    Partitions 1
    SCSI Bus Not Available
    Sectors/Track 63
    Size 2.73 TB (3,000,582,144,000 bytes)
    Total Cylinders 45,600
    Total Sectors 732,564,000
    Total Tracks 11,628,000
    Tracks/Cylinder 255
    Partition Disk #2, Partition #0
    Partition Size 2.73 TB (3,000,457,232,384 bytes)
    Partition Starting Offset 135,266,304 bytes

Drive #3:
    Manufacturer (Standard disk drives)
    Model Fantom External HDD USB Device
    Bytes/Sector 512
    Media Loaded Yes
    Media Type Removable media
    Partitions 1
    SCSI Bus Not Available
    Sectors/Track 63
    Size 1.82 TB (2,000,396,321,280 bytes)
    Total Cylinders 243,201
    Total Sectors 3,907,024,065
    Total Tracks 62,016,255
    Tracks/Cylinder 255
    Partition Disk #3, Partition #0
    Partition Size 1.82 TB (2,000,396,289,024 bytes)
    Partition Starting Offset 32,256 bytes

Comment: Do file system and surfaces tests on both drives. Test them with the drive manufacturers' diagnostics.  Take the drives out of the USB enclosures and try the task with them directly attached (via SATA or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this problem was related to USB drivers and/or USB3.0.  I happened to connect my USB3.0 drive to a USB2 port and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is USB3.0 specific.

From my experience, what seems to happen is that somehow, the USB3.0 drivers get corrupted when you attach new USB3.0 devices in some cases.

I had the same problem in Windows 10. I uninstalled USB3.0 drivers and rebooted and Windows automatically reinstalls the appropriate drivers.

The problem creeps back in when I use different USB3.0 hardware, especially flash drives. Each time, my solution has been to reinstall the USB3.0 drivers. Hope that helps.