# What is a "semaphore timeout period?"

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I have some personal experience with the [semaphore timeout period error](https://superuser.com/questions/735987/win7-x64-large-copy-file-creation-error-the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expir). I was able to get the error resolved, but that still left me asking, what in the world is a "semaphore timeout period?" How can I prevent it from happening? Why does it only happen when large data transfers are in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and a mutex) is a *[synchronization object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*, used to communicate amongst various processes sharing a resource. For example,if you had multiple threads performing division checks for primality, you would want to assign different divisors after each test finishes.

A thread needs to check the semaphore using a *[Wait Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#single-objectwaitfunctions)* to see if the object is free. However, to handle deadlocks should one thread fail to release a semaphore, wait functions can specify a finite time-out, the message you see. If a transfer takes too long, then the semaphore controlling it expires.

For more information, see *[WaitForSingleObject function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*, or the [C++ Tutorial Multi-Threaded Programming](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreaded2B.php).

So what might you do in a real-world situation when transferring large files over a network with limited bandwidth?

1. Compress the files (XML data, in particular, compresses ~10:1 with Zip).
2. Break the files into chunks (a nuisance, but applicable to any file type).
3. Improve bandwidth. For example, I found SSH/SFTP *extremely* slow on an older server, but when RAM was added, data transferred more rapidly.

Answer (score -1):

I tripped on the solution for the timeout -- I was backing up my HD to an external drive and kept on getting the semephore time-out error and found a suggestion to change USB connection and success. Problem gone.